# Ractive transition not working for partial on update

Tags: ractivejs

**UPDATE**:
Here's a fiddle. It works a little better than my own real app, but still highlights a potential bug (or my misunderstanding). Notice that the "outro" transition doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/k4a81fza/1/

Original:

This is a partial I'm using inside of a parent Ractive:

```
<script id="session_tpl" type="text/ractive">
  <div>
    <a href="#" on-tap="showDetail">
      {{#if p.project !== null}}
        <p intro-outro="fly">
          {{project}}
        </p>
      {{/if}}
    </a>
  </div>
</script>
```

Here's how I'm trying to then update the data (which is changed from a different ractive that represents a detail view):

```
daysRac.set('days[1].sessions[2].project', null);
```

The `<p>` tag in in the template successfully disappears, but without the transition. I've tried other transitions and tweaked duration and delay, but it always is just instantly removed.

Ideally I want different outro and intro transitions, which I thought I could achieve with something like this:

```
daysRac.set(keypathToProject, null, function(){
  daysRac.set(keypathToProject, "The New Value");
});
```

Again, that works to update the project value displayed in the `<p>`, but without transitions.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Basic transition seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/1zpqshfa/1/. Check the console to see if message that transition is not loaded. Otherwise, perhaps data or template references are not as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug, I submitted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1271).

The problem is that Ractive updates `{{description}}` to `null` before the transition starts. It [works correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/c3y5qr86/) if you don't use an expression, i.e. if you change `{{#if description !== null}}` to `{{#if describtion}}`.

Comment: Ah good catch Martin. Using something other than a check for null should solve it for me. Thanks!